# Is there any way to see who downvotes a post?

Tags: support, voting

I've made several posts on the main Drupal site that have been downvoted with no explanation. Is there any way to see who is doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. There is a longer and relevant discussion on the topic here: [A call to provide explanations for a down-voted question](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/652/a-call-to-provide-explanations-for-a-down-voted-question)

After taking a look at the two questions you have with a -1 score, my guess is that [Module to allow multiple paths for a single node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/module-to-allow-multiple-paths-for-a-single-node) was considered "to obvious", since the functionality is already in core. Showing that you had attempted to figure this out on your own first might have made a difference.

This one on the other hand  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28575/images-uploaded-using-media-gallery-w-plupload-do-not-attach-to-node very much looks like a bug, belongs in the issue queue, and is as such off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't think it qualified as a bug, since it obviously works for a lot of other people. That makes me think that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Actually, since the issue it already reported in the issue queue, it doesn't really matter if it's a bug or not. We don't duplicate the issue queue here. That said, after reading the issue, I would assume it's a bug, although perhaps a rare one.

Comment: @Letharion We don't accept questions about bugs, on _Drupal Answers_; a question that is asked on Drupal.org (and that is not about a bug in a module) can be asked here too. Certainly, if somebody keeps asking a question on Drupal.org, asking it on _DA_, and answering on _DA_ giving the same answer given on Drupal.org, that would be a different matter.

Comment: I will take note on that difference. :)

Comment: In all fairness, I don't think the path thing is obvious.  One, you have to realize the alias and path are used interchangeably.  Two, that page is buried.  Three, it is a little weird that you can't set additional aliases on the node/edit page.

Comment: I just suggested that was a possibility, the down-vote isn't mine, and I agree that's it is not necessarily obvious.

Answer (score 3):

SE developers are the only ones who can see that data, not even diamond moderators have access to it. I didn't downvote your question about Plupload but I did vote to close it as off topic (for the reason @Letharion mentioned).

The important thing to remember is **don't take it personally!**

Voting up/down/to close a question is merely about quality control for the site; every question needs to stand on its own and be potentially useful to future visitors. If others in the community don't think a particular question holds up to those criteria, then downvoting/voting to close are the only methods (besides commenting) that any of us can use to voice that opinion.

I do agree it can be frustrating to receive downvotes without a comment though; as far as I've seen in the SE network it's very much encouraged to leave a comment so that the question can be improved upon.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to see who down-voted you, as votes on posts are anonymous by design.
It is not even an information that a normal user would need to know, as there is a mechanism to auto-detect votes irregularities (both up-votes, and down-votes) and correct those votes by removing them. Moderators can see suspiciously high levels of activity between users. This means that moderators are able to detect cases of cross-voting, where you vote a user's posts, and that user votes for your posts.

In your case, there isn't anything suspicious, as you got 4 down-votes, since April 25, 2011; of those down-votes, one is the automatic down-vote given to questions closed as off-topic. You also got 10 points removed because users who up-voted your questions, and then removed their up-votes.

[image: screenshot]

To add to what Clive said, leaving comments about what is wrong with the post is recommended, but down-voters are not forced to leave a comment for the simple fact voting is anonymous by design. If they were forced to leave a comment by the software, you would have a chance to guess who down-voted, except in the case there are more comments from users who didn't down-vote, but that probably happens rarely, on small Stack Exchange sites.

The general reason of a down-vote is given in the tooltip for the voting button.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have to be honest, I find people on this site to be a bit overzealous in downvoting, way more so than on any of the other SE sites. Just because a question "isn't useful" to someone who's clearly an experienced Drupal developer doesn't mean the answer wouldn't be useful to other people like the original poster (who are most likely beginners, as am I.)

Comment: Getting 3 down-votes over the period of a year is not that much; if _Drupal Answers_ were a bit overzealous, the down-votes could have been more than that. "It is not helpful" is not referring for who down-votes, but for future readers; at least that is what I get it to mean because, otherwise, who is a Drupal expert would down-vote every single question.